# undefined is not a function(evaluating properties[typeof Symbol === "function"?Symbol.iterator:"@@iterator"]()') React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, babeljs

It used to work well but this error suddenly occurred after updating some project dependencies. It comes from a component that render `slate.js` object (I'm not rendering the editor but the text). I read that this error can be solved by updating `babel-preset-react-native`, but mine is already the most updated. I've also import `babel-polyfill` in the entry file.

I've found quite a few issue like this in github but doesn't find a solution for me.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd-mobile": "^2.1.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.49.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.375",
    "slate": "^0.32.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^22.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.6.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^22.2.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}


{
  "presets": ["react-native","react-native-dotenv"],
  "plugins": [["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }]]
}
```

I use typescript for the app, here's the tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./src",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "types": ["system","node"],
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is an old one, did you solve your problem ?